# Labeling a row in a dataframe according to a label in another dataframe with minimum distance - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, distance

If have two dataframes as the following.

df1 =

```
    A           B           C        Label
    1.5        2            1.5        1
    2.5        3            2.5        2
    3.5        4            3.5        3
```

and df2  =

```
    A           B           C     
    2          2            2       
    3          3            3        
    4          4            4       
    3          3            3
```

I would like  to add the label to each row where the  distance between the row is the minimum. That would be:

```
    A           B           C   Label  
    3          3            3      2
    2          2            2      1 
    4          4            4      3
    3          3            3      2
```

What i tried:

```
final_label = []
final_label.append(min(distance.euclidean(df2.iloc[i,:],
df1.iloc[j,:]) for j in len(df1)  for i in len(df2))
```

Note: It is important that the order of df2 isn't lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use numpy's broadcasting to compute the euclidean distance between each pair and find the minimum value with `argmin`.

```
v = ((df1.iloc[:, :-1].values[:, None] - df2.values) ** 2).sum(-1).argmin(0)
df2.assign(Label=df1.Label.iloc[v].values)

   A  B  C  Label
0  2  2  2      1
1  3  3  3      2
2  4  4  4      3
3  3  3  3      2
```

Comment: @MaxU haha I'm not 100% sure, but this was a best guess answer, I guess? ;D

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ If I use more rows than df1 I get: positional indexers are out-of-bounds. If I don't I get: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz Fixed that, it should work now. Please check if it is correct. Also, I think the last row's label should be 2.

Comment: Worked flawlessly now!

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz Okay. Just make sure it is what you want. The label for the last row is 2, and the order of `df2` is not altered (whereas it is, in your expected output). If all is well, then cheers :-)

Comment: It is! I want the vectors ordered like in df2, I don't mind if label isn't ordered

Answer (score 3):

`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` + `np.where`

```
ary=scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(df1[['A', 'B', 'C']], df2[['A', 'B', 'C']], metric='euclidean')
order=np.where(ary==ary.min(1)[:,None])
df2['New']=df1.reindex(order[1]).Label.values

df2
Out[612]: 
   A  B  C  Label  New
0  3  3  3      2    2
1  2  2  2      1    1
2  4  4  4      3    3
```

EDIT : By using cold's argmin()

```
ary = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(df2[['A', 'B', 'C']], df1[['A', 'B', 'C']], metric='euclidean')

df2['New']=df1.reindex(ary.argmin(1)).Label.values


df2
Out[659]: 
   A  B  C  Label  New
0  3  3  3      2    2
1  2  2  2      1    1
2  4  4  4      3    3
3  3  3  3      3    2
```

Comment: You can use `argmin` to get `order` more easily. Also, why the reindexing? How does it work?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ np. where ,return the column and index, index is the df2 closeness match one's order in df1, then I reindex the df1, match the order.. :-)

Comment: The dataframes arent of the same size, I will edit it for further clarification.

Comment: @Wen I get the error:  cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz your df1, contain duplicate key?

Comment: Nope, literally using the example except with different numbers.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz you can using cold’s method. Assign the label ,the different from us is how to get the matrix